# java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException

Tags: java, sql, derby

I am getting this error when running a save insert/update command:

```
SEVERE: null
java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: The statement was aborted because it would have caused a duplicate key value in a unique or primary key constraint or unique index identified by 'SQL110207185137350' defined on 'EMPLOYEE'.
null, Boris Wilkins
```

If anyone can spot why this error is happening it would be great.

here is the code:

```
 /////////////////////////////////////////////
    ///   UPDATE methods
    /** Saves an existing pkg in the database */
    public void save(Employee pkg) throws DataException {
        Connection conn = null;
        try {
            conn = ConnectionPool.getInstance().get();
            save(pkg, conn);
            conn.commit();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            try {
                conn.rollback();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                throw new DataException("We're currently upgrading our site to serve you better.", e);
            }
            throw new DataException("Problem saving the Employee", e);

        } finally {
            ConnectionPool.getInstance().release(conn);

        }//update
    }

    /** Internal method to update a pkg in the database */
    void save(Employee emp, Connection conn) {
        // update the cache
        Cache.getInstance().put(emp.getId(), emp);
        // if not dirty, return
        if (!emp.isDirty()) {
            return;
        }
        // call either update() or insert()
        if (emp.isObjectAlreadyInDB()) {
            update(emp, conn);
        } else {
            insert(emp, conn);
        }

    }//save

    /** Saves an existing pkg to the database */



    //NEED HELP WITH EXECUTE STATEMENT!!!


    private void update(Employee pkg, Connection conn) {
        try {
            // run the update SQL
            PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE Employee SET id=?, name1=?, username1=?, password=?, type=? WHERE id=?");
            pstmt.setString(1, pkg.getId());
            pstmt.setString(2, pkg.getName1());
            pstmt.setString(3, pkg.getUserName1());
            pstmt.setString(4, pkg.getPassword());
            pstmt.setString(5, pkg.getType());
            pstmt.setString(6, pkg.getId());

            pstmt.executeUpdate();
            pstmt.close();
            // update the dirty variable
            pkg.setDirty(false);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(EmployeeDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }


    }

    /** Inserts a new pkg into the database */
    private void insert(Employee pkg, Connection conn) {
        try {
            // run the insert SQL
            PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT into Employee (id, name1, username1, password, type) values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
            pstmt.setString(1, pkg.getId());
            pstmt.setString(2, pkg.getName1());
            pstmt.setString(3, pkg.getUserName1());
            pstmt.setString(4, pkg.getPassword());
            pstmt.setString(5, pkg.getType());
            // update the dirty variable

            pstmt.execute();
            pstmt.close();
            pkg.setDirty(false);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(EmployeeDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

Code for alreadyInDB:

```
/** Returns whether the object is in the DB or not */
  boolean isObjectAlreadyInDB() {
    return objectAlreadyInDB;
  }//isObjectAlreadyInDB

  /** 
   * Sets whether the object is already in the DB.  This method
   * is called ONLY from the DAO responsible for this object.
   */
  void setObjectAlreadyInDB(boolean objectAlreadyInDB) {
    this.objectAlreadyInDB = objectAlreadyInDB;
  }//setObjectAlreadyInDB
```

Comment: Why does your update statement set the id? Shouldn't you only be setting the other fields? Not sure it's a problem, but seems odd.

Comment: Actually thinking about it a bit more, you might want to double check that's not causing the issue. DBs aren't my strength, but I could see a DB complaining about trying to update a primary key that already exists. At least eliminate it as a possibility.

Comment: Thank you for seeing that. I changed it, which I definitely needed to do, but still getting same error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This statement `emp.isObjectAlreadyInDB()` is obviously failing and returning `false` all the time, causing the same employee to be inserted everytime you run the code, thus violating the primary key or unique constraint you set up in that database table.

Answer (score 2):

I am using a tester class and i was accidentally creating an object with the same id as an object that was already in the DB.